# Single sender and multiple receiver processes using posix message queue in linux

Tags: linux, posix, sysv

Is there any way such that a writer process after sending a mesage to message queue using `mq_send()`, multiple reader processes can read the message using `mq_receive()`.  I expect 1 write to `mq` and 1 read from `mq`, the message is lost.

So I just want to know if my understanding is wrong. Is there any way so that a single writer and multiple reader processes can communicate using posix message queues.

Answer (score 11):

Yes your understanding is correct.  You can't do this reliably with POSIX message queues.  If you want to communicate the same message to different threads/processes reliably you should use a different queue for each reader.

You can do this if you switch to SYSV message queues.  [Msgsnd()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/msgop.2.html) and msgrcv() can manipulate the message type field of a message in some agreed upon protocol.  For instance the writer process will make the message type of the message the PID of the reader process; and the reader process will request to read only messages of that message type.  Note that this still requires the writer to write a message for each reader process.